# PHP (OR PYTHON) Merge all Included files into a single large file (recursive?)

Tags: php, python, recursion

I have a PHP script that uses includes. The files that are included also have their own includes. 
All files are in the same folder on a webserver. I would like a seperate PHP script that will merge all these
into a single PHP file. I would supply the new script with the file to begin processing from (e.g index.php above).
How do I do this using PHP? For example say I have these files:

```
---------------------
index.php
<?php

*other code1*
include 'header.php';
*other code2*

?>

----------------------
header.php
<?php

*other code3*
include 'subheader.php';
*other code4*

?>


----------------------
subheader.php
<?php

*other code5*

?>


The result of the script begining from the index.php would be:

merged_file.php
<?php

*other code1*
    *other code3*
        *other code5*
    *other code4*
*other code2*

?>
```

i.e the code will all be in a single large file and executed in the exact same order as before.

So basically it will go through the script and everytime it finds an include it will replace the include with the relevent PHP code from the given include file and it will replace the code for any includes in that include untill all code has been merged into a single file (recursive function?)

Note: i want the unparsed PHP code returned in the file.

Thanks in advance

Edit: I understand its generally better practice to have modularized code but that is not my question. I am asking how I can achive this? Not the benefit of modularized vs 
un-modularized code.

Comment: What's wrong with just using `include`?

Comment: What's the advantage of this? If it's just to move the code all in one file for editing, copy/paste will be more efficient unless there are 100s or more includes happening.

Comment: I think you maybe are confusing `include` with `recursion` ?  Are you trying to move all code into one file or include only once? I would keep your code seperate, and have includes, its easier in the long run as your code grows (so you don't get stuck with a giant 1 script app)

Comment: And with this sort of design, if there's ever a chance of including the same thing twice where it only needs to execute once, I'd recommend using include_once.

Comment: That question title is completely useless. Please fix it.

Comment: I actually find this to be an interesting question. Clearly the OP knows how to use `include()`, and I can imagine scenarios where you'd like to be able to merge included files... for instance, so I could post a particularly hairy problem on SO

Comment: I understand the its generally better practice to have modularized code but that is not my question. I am asking how I can do this?

Answer (score 3):

**My comment from above**

> I think you maybe are confusing include with recursion ? Are you
>   trying to move all code into one file or include only once? I would
>   keep your code seperate, and have includes, its easier in the long run
>   as your code grows (so you don't get stuck with a giant 1 script app)

**Possible solution**

I think what you are asking is *"how do I only include the files once?"*

I would say, update the include files to have the [include_once()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php) call. As it will not re-include those files as you combine your code together.

This will let you have a working example as you flush things out, and clean up.

**Updated Answer**

Ok, based on feedback, if you want to combine all files, you would have to go through a process where you have a primary PHP script (or other language) which would

1. Recursively read through each and every *.php file
2. When it hits an `include` or `require` it should open that file
3. Ultimately parse the files as TEXT and then output TEXT in 1 giant file.

Comment: I don't think this is what is being asked. The OP wants to know how to merge all included php files (including files that are included in the included files) into a single long script. I admit that it would generally be bad practice, but that's the question

Comment: Omitting if its good or wrong question is about how to achieve that and not if that approach is good or bad

Comment: I want to go from a script currently using multiple "includes inside includes inside includes" to a single script in one large file (made up of all the small include files). To do this I require a new seperate PHP script/function that will combine the current folder containing the PHP script/include files into a single PHP file.

Answer (score 3):

I think this solves your problem [phpcompiler.org](http://phpcompiler.org/doc/latest/runningphc.html#including-files)

phc has initial support for compile-time processing of PHP’s include built-in. Enabling this feature inserts the included statements in the AST in the place of the include statement. Included functions, classes and interfaces become part of the file’s top-level scope. In the event that phc is not able to process the include statement (for example, if the file cannot be found), a warning is issued, and the include statement is left in place.